# Automatically create schema on SQL Server using SQLBulkCopy in .NET

Tags: .net, sql

I use SQLBulkCopy to copy a .NET datatable to a temporary SQL Server table.

Is there a way to dynamically create this temporary SQL Server table from .NET code without using SMO?

E.g. dynamically creating a "CREATE TABLE" statement in .NET?

If somebody has a solution / some running code for this problem I would really appreciate it!

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy does not automatically create the table for you, but you can always fall back on SqlCommand to do this.